# In rails Active Admin, how do I pass a value to prefill a new model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Let's say I have a column of remote staff and each of those staff can either be home worker or remote worker.

From the remote staff index page, I can click on create home worker and it will take me to the new home worker create page.

The following builds me a link that takes me to the create home worker page..

```
column :home_worker do |remote_staff|
      if remote_staff.home_worker
        link_to("Home worker ##{remote_staff.home_worker.id}", admin_home_worker_path(remote_staff.home_worker), method: :get)
      else
        link_to('Create Home Worker', redirect_to_home_worker_create_admin_remote_staff_path(remote_staff), method: :get)
      end
    end
```

Let's say all remote staff also have full names and so do home workers
How do I pre-fill the create home worker full name column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it...
I just needed to put the following into the new home worker f.inputs and then pass that value as full_name

```
remote_staff_full_name = RemoteStaff.find(params['home_worker']["remote_staff_id"]).full_name unless params['home_worker'].nil?
```

```
f.input :full_name, label: "Full name", :input_html => { :value => remote_staff_full_name }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more improved generic version that sets(overrides) value only for new records:

```ruby
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    attr_name = :barcode
    attr_value = resource.new_record? ? params[attr_name] : resource.send(attr_name)
    f.input(attr_name, input_html: { value: attr_value })
  end
end
```